# Is it clear what "facility" means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A native speaker wrote this text. Is it clear what he means by "facility"? Does it refer to the museum? Would it be better to use the plural "facilities" to mean the different facilities in the museum?

> I am writing to offer my services as an unpaid volunteer at your
> museum. I have always loved your **facility** and spent years wandering
> through it both as a child and as an adult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facility).

*Facilities* (in a building) can be used as a euphemism for *toilet facilities*, so it would sound a bit odd to me, as though the writer particularly liked the museum toilets!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So the singular "facility" should be used and it means the museum?

Comment: The singular is more appropriate than the plural in this context. The writer obviously meant the museum.